# How to restore a dictionary variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dictionary variable in my model

```
evaluation = {}
evaluation['accuracy'] = ...
evaluation['f1'] = ...
evaluation['precesion'] = ...
evaluation['recall'] = ....
```

After training and saving the model, I want to load the saved meta graph and restore variables. I want to get the placeholders from the graph by name

```
evaluation = graph.get_operation_by_name("evaluation").outputs[0]
```

and then can use it

```
evaluation = sess.run(evaluation, {input_x: ...})
```

I think I need to set a name for my variable but when I tried

```
evaluation = tf.Variable({}, name="evaluation")
```

I got the following error

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'dict'> to Tensor. Contents: {}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no dictionary variables in tensorflow. Your dictionary is in python and is not stored in the tensorflow graph. If you want your dictionary after loading the graph you will have to recreate it:

```
evaluation = {}
evaluation["placeholder_name"] = graph.get_tensor_by_name('placeholder_name:0')
```